# Which folder should i put into filezilla for ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filezilla

I have the following directory structure:
[image: directory structure]

Which files must I drag into remote site of Filezilla for this ROR project?

Comment: Ruby is not php. Simply copying directory structure will not give you working app.

Comment: hi guys, i was new to ruby and thought it would have been similar to php. i used git instead. cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When deploying a ROR project you should must use a VPN server. Have you used git for your project? Try to deploy in heroku first. To test your site and have a good practice when deploying rails.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Comment: I think the OP is asking something a lot less trivial than having to tap into a VPN and send something through a tunnel.

Comment: Are you confusing VPN and SSH? BTW, neither is _required_.

Comment: heroku works but yeah @JoshBrody is right. Looking for a simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question would be: everything

But most likely, copying everything is not gonna make it run, here is why: Rails applications live in separate processes that have to be specifically maintained. On your dev machine, you do this with `bundle exec rails server`. This is a key difference to how the apache php module works for php apps: There the php interpreter is embedded within the apache process and therefore shares its life cycle automatically.

If you have control over the server you are deploying to, I recommend to start with the Phusion passenger apache module. It takes care of starting your rails processes as needed. In case you are using ubuntu 14:04, I can't recommend to just `apt-get install libapche2-mod-passenger` because I had many problems with it.

If the server is maintained by somebody else, I'd ask this someone for a solution.

I hope this helps.